# Decomposition of matrix

Tags: matrix-decomposition

How we decompose or break matrix $A$ in the following form.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} {a_1}^2 & a_1a_2 & ... a_1a_n \\
 a_2a_1 & {a_2}^2 & ... a_2a_n \\.... \\
 a_na_1 & a_na_2 & ... {a_n}^2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_1 & ... a_1 \\
 a_2 & a_2 & ... a_2 \\.... \\
 a_n & a_n & ... a_n\end{pmatrix}×\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_1 & ... a_1 \\
 a_2 & a_2 & ... a_2 \\.... \\
 a_n & a_n & ... a_n\end{pmatrix}$$

My Attempt:

Taking RHS = $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_1 & ... a_1 \\
 a_2 & a_2 & ... a_2 \\.... \\
 a_n & a_n & ... a_n\end{pmatrix}×\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_1 & ... a_1 \\
 a_2 & a_2 & ... a_2 \\.... \\
 a_n & a_n & ... a_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} {a_1}^2+a_1a_2+...+a_1a_n & {a_1}^2+a_1a_2+...+a_1a_n & ... {a_1}^2+a_1a_2+...+a_1a_n \\
 a_2a_1+{a_2}^2+...+a_1a_n & a_2a_1+{a_2}^2+...+a_1a_n & ... a_2a_1+{a_2}^2+...+a_1a_n \\.... \\
 a_na_1+a_na_2+...+{a_n}^2 & a_na_1+a_na_2+...+{a_n}^2 & ... a_na_1+a_na_2+...+{a_n}^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

I couldn't proceed it further. Please help me.

Comment: For matrix A, should the last element on the 2nd row be $a_2a_n$ instead of $a_1a_n$?

Comment: Thanks for point out my mistake. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decomposition you post is wrong. A simple counterexample: Let $n=2$, $a_1=1$ and $a_2=0$. We have
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1 &a_1\\
a_2 & a_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1 &a_1\\
a_2 & a_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\
0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\
0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\
0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\neq\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\
0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1^2 &a_2\\
a_2a_1 & a_2^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

A correct decomposition is
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1^2 & a_1a_2 & \dots & a_1a_n\\
a_2a_1 & a_2^2 &\dots & a_2a_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_na_1 & a_na_2 &\dots & a_n^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & 0 & \dots &0\\
0& a_2 &\dots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0& 0 &\dots & a_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n\\
a_1 & a_2 &\dots & a_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_1 & a_2 &\dots & a_n\end{pmatrix}.$$
To obtain the above decomposition, simply note that all elements in the $j$-th row have a common factor $a_j$, for all $j=1,\dots,n$.

Or noting that all elements on the $j$-th column of $A$ have a common factor $a_j$, which yields
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1^2 & a_1a_2 & \dots & a_1a_n\\
a_2a_1 & a_2^2 &\dots & a_2a_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_na_1 & a_na_2 &\dots & a_n^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_1 & \dots & a_1\\
a_2 & a_2 &\dots & a_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_n & a_n &\dots & a_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & 0 & \dots &0\\
0& a_2 &\dots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0& 0 &\dots & a_n\end{pmatrix}.$$

In fact, the second decomposition also follows from the first one right away, as $A$ is symmetric, i.e., $A=A^T$.

Comment: I think you are right. I saw this question in local Indian book as it is.https://photos.app.goo.gl/FsGyTeeJDmrq66fG8